# How do I print both "from" and "to" of Gradle Copy task?

Tags: gradle

I need to debug a Gradle Copy task.

How do I print for each copied file both "from" and "to"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The task type `Copy` provides a method [`eachFile`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/AbstractCopyTask.html#eachFile-org.gradle.api.Action-) for this use case. The objects passed to the `Action` (or `Closure`) argument are of type [`FileCopyDetails`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/file/FileCopyDetails.html). Those objects provide properties like `sourcePath` and `path` that can be used to log both the source and the destination of the copied file:

```
task myCopyTask(type: Copy) {
    from ...
    into ...
    eachFile { file ->
        println file.sourcePath
        println file.path
    }
}
```